# ActionBarSherlock tabs with preferences

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, fragment

I want to support api level 9 and still using fragments and tabs. In one of my tab i need to make preferenceFragment, but there is no SherlockFragmentPreferences in library, only activity. 
How i can solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Find nice realisation of FragmentPrefences with support 
at https://github.com/kolavar/android-support-v4-preferencefragment